# Addition of named array breaks Kendo dataSource bind to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm binding a JS KendoUI dropdownlist to JSON (not using a model) which recently has been changed by adding a named array to the object (in efforts to format the JSON for a Kendo TreeView control). This broke a few things of course. The original JSON format looked like this (an array of objects):

```
[
 {
   "COLUMN_NAME": "OBJECTID",       
   "DATA_TYPE": "esriFieldTypeOID",              
   "CATEGORY": "Feature Data"
  },
  {
   "COLUMN_NAME": "Brand",       
   "DATA_TYPE": "esriFieldTypeString",              
   "CATEGORY": "Feature Data"
  },...    
]
```

now it looks like this (an object with a named array, with objects):

```
{
 "Hydrant": [
  {
   "COLUMN_NAME": "OBJECTID",       
   "DATA_TYPE": "esriFieldTypeOID",              
   "CATEGORY": "Feature Data"
  },
  {
   "COLUMN_NAME": "Brand",       
   "DATA_TYPE": "esriFieldTypeString",              
   "CATEGORY": "Feature Data"
  },...
],
"DisplayField": "Description",
"DefaultField" : "HydrantID"    
}
```

I assumed I could simply define the schema to "Hydrant" or set the dataText/ValueFields to "Hydrant.COLUMN_NAME" but no luck. **What am I overlooking?** I am binding this JSON format response to a dropdownlist using the "COLUMN_NAME" to populate it.

bonus: how could I use the "DefaultField" to set the default selection in the dropdownlist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`schema.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) field of the `DataSource` configuration to identify the field from the response to use for its data:

```
schema: { data: 'Hydrant' }
```

Comment: Oh man, duh. Thanks. I had left it blank due to a previous JSON format. Someone say coffee?